# Why my data is not written into the plist file?

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to make a module using Swift that can add a class to the database(ClassA.plist). The code is like this:

```
class AddClass:UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var txtClassName: UITextField!


@IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
    let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ClassA", ofType:"plist")
    let array = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: plistPath!)
    let AddData = NSDictionary(object: txtClassName.text!, forKey: "name" as NSCopying)

    array?.add(AddData)

    array?.write(toFile: plistPath!, atomically: false)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        super.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And my storyboard is like this:

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyUeh.png)
[Save Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMrwb.png)

However, as I write something in the textfield and click Save, nothing changed in my database. No waring, error or logs is shown.Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try dictionery instead of array

Comment: Use this answer if it makes sense.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697247/how-to-create-plist-files-programmatically-in-iphone

Comment: As has been written in so many other posts, an app's bundle is readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write to a file in the app bundle. The app bundle is read-only. You will need to copy your file to one of your sandbox directories like the documents directory before you will be able to change it.

Comment: There are many duplicates this could be closed as but I couldn't find any in Swift.

Comment: And now thanks to Christian, this thread can be the Swift answer to this perennial question...

Comment: Actually, I finally found one - and it's your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am sorry that I did not know that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @rmaddy, Christian's answer covers copying the file from the bundle to the documents directory before modifying it, which is a useful twist on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As many have pointed out, the app's bundle is read-only. What you can do is copy the file if you really want to use it and put it in the documentDirectory where you can read and write to it.

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let plistPath = paths.appending("/data.plist")
let fileManager = FileManager.default

if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: plistPath)
{
  // Default plist name is Info. Just using ClassA
  let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ClassA", ofType: "plist")
  try! fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundle!, toPath: plistPath)
}


let data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath)

data?.setObject("Hello World", forKey: "name" as NSCopying)
data?.write(toFile: plistPath, atomically: true)

print(data)
```